# gnuplot without intermediary files?

Tags: php, python, svg, gnuplot, cgi-bin

I got python code that looks something like this

```
import subprocess

outdata = """0 45
1 35
2 45
3 35
4 45
5 35
6 45
7 35
8 45""" # etc... one for every minute of a day
f = open("data.txt", 'w')
f.write(outdata)
f.close()

filename = "graph"
title    = "today"
plottext = """
set terminal svg size 2560,1440 enhanced font 'Arial,40'
set output '""" + filename + """.svg'
set title '""" + title + """'
set xrange [0:1440]
set yrange [0:]
set xtics ("00" 0, "01" 60, "02" 120, "03" 180, "04" 240, "05" 300, "06" 360, "07" 420, "08" 480, "09" 540, "10" 600, "11" 660, "12" 720, "13" 780, "14" 840, "15" 900, "16" 960, "17" 1020, "18" 1080, "19" 1140, "20" 1200, "21" 1260, "22" 1320, "23" 1380, "24" 1440 )
plot 'data.txt' using 1:2 with lines notitle
"""
f = open("plotfile.plt", 'w')
f.write(plottext)
f.close()

p = subprocess.call(["gnuplot", "plotfile.plt"])
```

Which works like a charm. But how do I create a graph with gnuplot from within Python (or an language) without using the temporary files 'data.txt' and 'plotfile.plt'?

This is done 30+ times per minute every minute, every hour, year around so skipping the temporary files would save disk time because it is not small amounts of data that is being processed.

Follow-up question, it is possible to also skip the out file and capture the xml for the svg-file in a variable? This is going to go in cgi-bin so I want to be able to call it like this:

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/cgi-bin/plot.py?table=table1&date=2016-12-07">
```

Edit: the Python module for gnuplot is not available for me.

Edit2: Another example in PHP that almost do what I want is

```
$outdata="0 33
1 44
2 55
3 44
4 33
5 44
 6 55";

$plottext = "set terminal svg size 2560,1440 enhanced font 'Arial,40'
set term svg size 2560,1440 enhanced font 'Arial,40'
set title ''
set xrange [0:1440]
set yrange [0:]
set xtics ('00' 0, '01' 60, '02' 120, '03' 180, '04' 240, '05' 300, '06' 360, '07' 420, '08' 480, '09' 540, '10' 600, '11' 660, '12' 720, '13' 780, '14' 840, '15' 900, '16' 960, '17' 1020, '18' 1080, '19' 1140, '20' 1200, '21' 1260, '22' 1320, '23' 1380, '24' 1440)
plot '-' using 1:2 with lines notitle\n". $outdata;

file_put_contents("plotfile.plt", $plottext);

exec("gnuplot plotfile.plt", $out);

foreach($out as $line)
{
    print $line."\n";
}
```

I would like to call it with something like exec("gnuplot $plottext", $out); so I can skip the file plotfile.plt because if two people try to access a plotted graph at the same time this setup might screw it up because everyone used plotfile.plt which is not the best of solution. We could use a long random name for each http request but keeping track of that many temp files and erase them is not elegant.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/22729602/2604213

Comment: Have you checked the answer I linked to? That should pretty much exactly be your use case: open gnuplot in a separate process, send script and data via stdin to that process and capture stdout which contains the produced image

Comment: I am looking for a more general solution that will work in any language. I have not been able to figure out how I can pass the entire contents of the *.plt file as an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plotting files with gnuplot withing Python is not the best solution. It is much better to use pyplot. That way you can input data inside the python code and save the graph as svg in a string.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
import io

plotfile = io.StringIO()
matplotlib.pyplot.plot([1,2,3,4], [1,2,1,4])
matplotlib.pyplot.ylabel('Y-axis')
matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel('X-axis')
matplotlib.pyplot.savefig(plotfile, format="svg", dpi = 100)
plotfile.seek(0)
svgstring = plotfile.read()
print(svgstring)
```

This is exactly what I wished for in my question. No file I/O in the potting and I get to keep the graph in the python code so it can be used for dynamic images in web apps.

Answer (score 0):

...it's a matter of taste...

As @Christoph wrote, you can also create your plot in Python with gnuplot. Put your data into a datablock and pass it together with the settings and plot commands to gnuplot. No need for intermediary files.
Something like this (tested with Python3.6) (Python professionals may want to improve it...)

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

settings = '''
reset session
set term svg
'''

# create some data and put it into datablock $Data
data_lines = ['$Data <<EOD']
for i in range(-10,11):
    data_lines.append(str(i) + '\t' + str(i*i))
data_lines.append('EOD\n')
data_str = '\n'.join(data_lines) + '\n'

plot_cmd ='''
plot $Data u 1:2 w lp pt 7
'''

gnuplot_str = settings + data_str + plot_cmd

gnuplot_path = r'C:\Programs\gnuplot\bin\gnuplot.exe'
# plot = Popen([gnuplot_path,'-p'],stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE)
plot = Popen([gnuplot_path],stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE)
output, error = plot.communicate(gnuplot_str.encode())

print(gnuplot_str)
print(output) # or use it elsewhere

#...
```

gnuplot code:

```
reset session
set term svg

$Data <<EOD
-10 100
-9  81
-8  64
-7  49
-6  36
-5  25
-4  16
-3  9
-2  4
-1  1
0   0
1   1
2   4
3   9
4   16
5   25
6   36
7   49
8   64
9   81
10  100
EOD

plot $Data u 1:2 w lp pt 7
```

Output SVG:

[image]