# `RuntimeError: Resource temporarily unavailable` for dask.array.map_blocks()

Tags: python, arrays, parallel-processing, dask, python-xarray

I have a function called `sig2z` that I want to apply over a dask array:

```
def sig2z(da, zr, zi, nvar=None, dim=None, coord=None):
    """
    Interpolate variables on \sigma coordinates onto z coordinates.

    Parameters
    ----------
    da : `dask.array`
        The data on sigma coordinates to be interpolated
    zr : `dask.array`
        The depths corresponding to sigma layers
    zi : `numpy.array`
        The depths which to interpolate the data on
    nvar : str (optional)
        Name of the variable. Only necessary when the variable is
        horizontal velocity.

    Returns
    -------
    dai : `dask.array`
        The data interpolated onto a spatial uniform z coordinate
    """

    if np.diff(zi)[0] < 0. or zi.max() <= 0.:
        raise ValueError("The values in `zi` should be postive and increasing.")
    if np.any(np.absolute(zr[0]) < np.absolute(zr[-1])):
        raise ValueError("`zr` should have the deepest depth at index 0.")
    if zr.shape != da.shape[-3:]:
        raise ValueError("`zr` should have the same "
                        "spatial dimensions as `da`.")

    if dim == None:
        dim = da.dims
    if coord == None:
        coord = da.coords
    N = da.shape
    nzi = len(zi)
    if len(N) == 4:
        dai = np.empty((N[0],nzi,N[-2],N[-1]))
    elif len(N) == 3:
        dai = np.empty((nzi,N[-2],N[-1]))
    else:
        raise ValueError("The data should at least have three dimensions")
    dai[:] = np.nan

    zi = -zi[::-1] # ROMS has deepest level at index=0

    if nvar=='u':  # u variables
        zl = .5*(zr.shift(eta_rho=-1, xi_rho=-1)
                 + zr.shift(eta_rho=-1)
                )
    elif nvar=='v': # v variables
        zl = .5*(zr.shift(xi_rho=-1)
                 + zr.shift(eta_rho=-1, xi_rho=-1)
                )
    else:
        zl = zr

    for i in range(N[-1]):
        for j in range(N[-2]):
            # only bother for sufficiently deep regions
            if zl[:,j,i].min() < -1e2:
                # only interp on z above topo
                ind = np.argwhere(zi >= zl[:,j,i].copy().min())
                if len(N) == 4:
                    for s in range(N[0]):
                        dai[s,:len(ind),j,i] = _interpolate(da[s,:,j,i].copy(),
                                                            zl[:,j,i].copy(),
                                                            zi[int(ind[0]):]
                                                           )
                else:
                    dai[:len(ind),j,i] = _interpolate(da[:,j,i].copy(),
                                                      zl[:,j,i].copy(),
                                                      zi[int(ind[0]):]
                                                     )

    return xr.DataArray(dai, dims=dim, coords=coord)
```

This works fine on xarray.DataArray but when I apply it to dask.array, I get the following error:

```
test = dsar.map_blocks(sig2z, w[0].data, 
                      zr.chunk({'eta_rho':1,'xi_rho':1}).data, zi, 
                      dim, coord,
                      chunks=dai[0].chunks, dtype=dai.dtype
                      ).compute()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-d81bad2f4486> in <module>()
----> 1 test.compute()

/home/takaya/.conda/envs/arab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/base.py in compute(self, **kwargs)
     95             Extra keywords to forward to the scheduler ``get`` function.
     96         """
---> 97         (result,) = compute(self, traverse=False, **kwargs)
     98         return result
     99 

/home/takaya/.conda/envs/arab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/base.py in compute(*args, **kwargs)
    202     dsk = collections_to_dsk(variables, optimize_graph, **kwargs)
    203     keys = [var._keys() for var in variables]
--> 204     results = get(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
    205 
    206     results_iter = iter(results)

/home/takaya/.conda/envs/arab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/threaded.py in get(dsk, result, cache, num_workers, **kwargs)
     73     results = get_async(pool.apply_async, len(pool._pool), dsk, result,
     74                         cache=cache, get_id=_thread_get_id,
---> 75                         pack_exception=pack_exception, **kwargs)
     76 
     77     # Cleanup pools associated to dead threads

/home/takaya/.conda/envs/arab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/local.py in get_async(apply_async, num_workers, dsk, result, cache, get_id, rerun_exceptions_locally, pack_exception, raise_exception, callbacks, dumps, loads, **kwargs)
    519                         _execute_task(task, data)  # Re-execute locally
    520                     else:
--> 521                         raise_exception(exc, tb)
    522                 res, worker_id = loads(res_info)
    523                 state['cache'][key] = res

/home/takaya/.conda/envs/arab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/compatibility.py in reraise(exc, tb)
     58         if exc.__traceback__ is not tb:
     59             raise exc.with_traceback(tb)
---> 60         raise exc
     61 
     62 else:

/home/takaya/.conda/envs/arab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/local.py in execute_task(key, task_info, dumps, loads, get_id, pack_exception)
    288     try:
    289         task, data = loads(task_info)
--> 290         result = _execute_task(task, data)
    291         id = get_id()
    292         result = dumps((result, id))

/home/takaya/.conda/envs/arab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/local.py in _execute_task(arg, cache, dsk)
    269         func, args = arg[0], arg[1:]
    270         args2 = [_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args]
--> 271         return func(*args2)
    272     elif not ishashable(arg):
    273         return arg

/home/takaya/.conda/envs/arab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/array/core.py in getarray(a, b, lock)
     63         c = a[b]
     64         if type(c) != np.ndarray:
---> 65             c = np.asarray(c)
     66     finally:
     67         if lock:

/home/takaya/.conda/envs/arab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    529 
    530     """
--> 531     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    532 
    533 

/home/takaya/.conda/envs/arab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/indexing.py in __array__(self, dtype)
    425 
    426     def __array__(self, dtype=None):
--> 427         self._ensure_cached()
    428         return np.asarray(self.array, dtype=dtype)
    429 

/home/takaya/.conda/envs/arab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/indexing.py in _ensure_cached(self)
    422     def _ensure_cached(self):
    423         if not isinstance(self.array, np.ndarray):
--> 424             self.array = np.asarray(self.array)
    425 
    426     def __array__(self, dtype=None):

/home/takaya/.conda/envs/arab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    529 
    530     """
--> 531     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    532 
    533 

/home/takaya/.conda/envs/arab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/indexing.py in __array__(self, dtype)
    406 
    407     def __array__(self, dtype=None):
--> 408         return np.asarray(self.array, dtype=dtype)
    409 
    410     def __getitem__(self, key):

/home/takaya/.conda/envs/arab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    529 
    530     """
--> 531     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    532 
    533 

/home/takaya/.conda/envs/arab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/indexing.py in __array__(self, dtype)
    373     def __array__(self, dtype=None):
    374         array = orthogonally_indexable(self.array)
--> 375         return np.asarray(array[self.key], dtype=None)
    376 
    377     def __getitem__(self, key):

/home/takaya/.conda/envs/arab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    529 
    530     """
--> 531     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    532 
    533 

/home/takaya/.conda/envs/arab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/indexing.py in __array__(self, dtype)
    373     def __array__(self, dtype=None):
    374         array = orthogonally_indexable(self.array)
--> 375         return np.asarray(array[self.key], dtype=None)
    376 
    377     def __getitem__(self, key):

/home/takaya/.conda/envs/arab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/backends/netCDF4_.py in __getitem__(self, key)
     58         with self.datastore.ensure_open(autoclose=True):
     59             try:
---> 60                 data = getitem(self.get_array(), key)
     61             except IndexError:
     62                 # Catch IndexError in netCDF4 and return a more informative

netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx in netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable.__getitem__ (netCDF4/_netCDF4.c:39743)()

netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx in netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable._get (netCDF4/_netCDF4.c:49835)()

RuntimeError: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Could someone please tell me why I'm getting this error? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resource temporarily unavailable error with subprocess module in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22725165/resource-temporarily-unavailable-error-with-subprocess-module-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

pid numbers, open file descriptors, memory are limited resources.

[fork(2) manual says](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/fork.2.html) when `errno.EAGAIN` should happen:

```
[EAGAIN]  The system-imposed limit on the total number of processes under
          execution would be exceeded.  This limit is configuration-dependent.

[EAGAIN]  The system-imposed limit MAXUPRC () on the total number of processes
          under execution by a single user would be exceeded.
```

To reproduce the error more easily, you could add at the start of your program:

```
import resource

resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_NPROC, (20, 20))
```

The issue might be that all child processes are alive because you haven't called `p.stdin.close()` and gnuplot's stdin might be fully buffered when redirected to a pipe i.e., `gnuplot` processes might be stuck awaiting input. And/or your application uses too many file descriptors (file descriptors are inherited by child processes by default on Python 2.7) without releasing them.

If input doesn't depend on the output and the input is limited in size then use `.communicate()`:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

p = Popen("gnuplot", stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE,
          close_fds=True, # to avoid running out of file descriptors
          bufsize=-1, # fully buffered (use zero (default) if no p.communicate())
          universal_newlines=True) # translate newlines, encode/decode text
out, err = p.communicate("\n".join(['set terminal gif;', contents]))
```

`.communicate()` writes all input and reads all output (concurrently, so there is no deadlock) then closes p.stdin, p.stdout, p.stderr (even if input is small and gnuplot's side is fully buffered; EOF flushes the buffer) and waits for the process to finish (no zombies).

`Popen` calls `_cleanup()` in its constructor that [polls exit status of all known subprocesses](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/subprocess.py#l458) i.e., even if you won't call `p.wait()` there shouldn't be many zombie processes (dead but with unread status).

answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/22729602/4879665

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't help my issue.